# Scraping email addresses Beautiful Soup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I have been trying to scrape email addresses from a list of pages. One such page is https://protocol.dfat.gov.au/Public/Missions/5.

So far, this is what I have tried:

```
emails = []

url = "https://protocol.dfat.gov.au/Public/Missions/6"
req = Request(url, headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})

webpage = urlopen(req).read()

soup = BeautifulSoup(webpage, 'html.parser')
a_tags = soup.find_all('a')

for atag in a_tags:
    if "mailto:" in atag['href']:
        emails.append(atag.text)
```

It is returning an empty list. I would want to scrape all emails in that particular page.

Answer (score 1):

The data is loaded using `javascript`. Try using the [`requests-html`](https://docs.python-requests.org/projects/requests-html/en/latest/) package which has inbuilt support for rendering javascript content. See below sample.

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from requests_html import HTMLSession

emails = []

url = "https://protocol.dfat.gov.au/Public/Missions/6"

session = HTMLSession()
r = session.get(url)
r.html.render(timeout=20)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.html.html, 'html.parser')
a_tags = soup.find_all('a', href=True)


for atag in a_tags:
    if "mailto:" in atag['href']:
        emails.append(atag.text)
            
print(emails)
```